# bash case variable not empty

Tags: regex, bash, case

I'm using a case statement like this in one of my projects to check some combinations of variables:

```
fun(){
    case "$a:$b:$c" in
          *:*:*) echo fine;;
          *:2:*) echo ok;;
          3:*:*) echo good;;
              *) echo not ok;;
    esac
}
```

The goal of the first case `*:*:*)` is to check that one of the vars, lets say `$c` is **not empty**. But it's not working like that, it's basically the same as `*)` at the end and triggers false positive if `$c` is not set. I've tried to use `*:*:+` and `*:*:!''` no luck. So I've ended up using this:

```
fun(){
    c1=; [[ $c ]] && c1=1
    case "$a:$b:$c1" in
          *:*:1) echo fine;;
          *:2:*) echo ok;;
          3:*:*) echo good;;
              *) echo not ok;;
    esac
}
```

The question is - is there a better, more 'case' way?

Comment: BTW, you could replace `c1=; [[ $c ]] && c1=1` with `c1=${c:+1}`.

Comment: `*` matches *zero* or more characters, not *1* or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `?` glob, which matches exactly one character. In combination with `?*` this matches at least one character.

```
case "$a:$b:$c" in
     (*:*:?*) echo fine;;
     (*:2:?*) echo ok;;
     (3:*:?*) echo good;;
          (*) echo not ok;;
esac
```

I think you should change the order of the alternatives, since e.g. `3:2:1` will be fine and no triplet will ever be ok or good.